# ASP.NET MVC - Display same db table on multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I'm trying to make a webpage using ASP.net, where I want to display a table of lifting records for my local gym with values stored in a database.
On one page, I want to just display the records.
On another page, I want to able to log in as admin and be able to edit the table.

My problem is to view the same table on multiple pages (The database, and editfunction I've allready managed to create).

Here's my code in my controller to view and edit the database:

```
 public class TavlingsverksamhetController : Controller
{
    private RekorddatabasEntities db = new RekorddatabasEntities();

    // GET: Tavlingsverksamhet
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        List<Klubbrekord> rekordLista = db.Klubbrekord.ToList();
        return View(rekordLista);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        Klubbrekord rekordAttAndra = db.Klubbrekord.Find(id);
        return View(rekordAttAndra);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Klubbrekord andratRekord)
    {

        db.Entry(andratRekord).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

}
```

And here's the code in the associated View to the Controller:
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCtI8.png)

I thought I could copy the database code for another controller (for the reason to display and collect the same data), but it doesn't work..

Comment: So what is your problem? (and the code you have shown is for editing one record, not all records in the table)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can't seem to display the same table on another controllers view.. Is it something when I create the list?

Yes, but at the webpage, every row has a clickable link aside from the table where I can choose one row at a time to edit.

Comment: But you other view is for editing a single record. And you have not even shown that view, or explained what your trying to do and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question when first time 'played' with ASP.NET.
In order to show this DB table on other pages (for example Home/Index), just initialize new db and return in in view, like you do in your code;

```
private RekorddatabasEntities db = new RekorddatabasEntities();

public ActionResult Index()
{

    List<Klubbrekord> rekordLista = db.Klubbrekord.ToList();
    return View(rekordLista);
}
```